# Encryption algorithm with limited length public key / message

Tags: encryption

I require an encryption algorithm which work with a limited sized (<10 char) public key size and a limited (<10 char) encrypted message. Obviously that limits the content of the message, but that's fine; that will be short. Private key does not matter really length wise.

Is any algorithm exists like that? Or a direction to search in?

Comment: I know now secure asymmetric encryption that comes anywhere close to these constraints.

Comment: What do you mean by "char"? A byte? Or a printable ASCII character? Or a unicode codepoint?

Comment: Most Public Key Encryption Algorithms work very well with a limited sized public key. They are of course not very secure in that setup.

Comment: Printable ASCII char.